# How to initialize empty hint database

Tags: coq, ltac

I have several proofs that follow identical structure. First of them can be finished with `trivial`, all the other ones with `auto with foo_db`, where `foo_db` is a hint database populated with hints after the first proof is complete. I'd like to write an Ltac procedure that uses `auto with foo_db` to solve all these proofs. However, when running that Ltac to solve the first of my proofs `foo_db` does not yet exist and so Coq complains: `Error: No such Hint database: foo_db.`. Is there a way to initialize an empty hint database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a command `Create HintDb` that does exactly what you want.

```
Create HintDb foo_db.

Goal True.
  auto with foo_db nocore. (* no hints *)
  exact I.
Qed.
```

For demonstration purposes (to avoid solving the goal), I've also added the pseudo-db `nocore` to avoid using the standard library's hints. You probably want to just do `auto with foo_db`, to solve all the goals `trivial` would have solved.